# Joining a shape file and CSV file without losing/gaining data

Tags: r, join, dplyr, leaflet, shapefile

I am trying to join a .shp file (2644 Observations of small region polygons) with a .csv file (7,760 observations of monthly data for some of these small regions) in order to create an interactive leaflet map in R. I have tried using geojoin from library(tigris) and end up with only 2,644 observations if I do a left join on small region or 17,088 observations if I do an inner join on small regions. Similar issues arise using library(dplyr). Do you have any recommendations on how to perform this join without losing any of the the data from the .csv file and repeating the shape polygons for repeated small regions within the .csv as the data repeats monthly?

Comment: Please provide a sample of data and the code you have tried

Comment: Can't share data due to an NDA, but the methods I've tried have been 'NewData<- inner_join(file.shp, file.csv, by = c("small region"))'       and   NewData <- geo_join(file.shp,file.csv,'small region','small region',how = "inner") as well as using the left join counterparts for each

Answer (score 0):

You can always share a dummy data like this, Asssuming I have understood your data correctly:

```
shpfile =data.frame(region=rep(paste("Place",1:4),each=3),coord=sample(1:100,12))

csvfile = data.frame(region=rep(paste("Place",1:4),each=12),months= rep(month.abb,4),val=sample(1:100,48))

library(dplyr)
df1= merge(shpfile,csvfile,by="region",all.y=TRUE)
df1
```